# Foodizone android studio running issue

Tags: flutter

I have foodizone flutter app, but when I try to build it in the android studio it gives an error main file missing, How to fix it?

i have tried to clean  with flutter  clean still not fixed

Comment: Share the screenshot of the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same and it is just needed to set the main file in the flutter build config.
1 Find the "add configuration" button just press than left side select "flutter" click the + button, then select flutter.
2. Then give a naming and choose the entry point and click the OK button
3. Locate the Flutter Target Selector drop-down button. This shows a list of available targets.